# do you mind + if-clause or ~ing

Tags: gerunds

> Do you mind if I open the window? ([OALD](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/mind_2))

If I use *do you mind my opening the window* or *do you mind me opening the window*, are both plausible or not?

Comment: They're all acceptable and all equivalent. Some 'authorities' will tell you that they have subtly different emphases, but I think this is false. Individual speakers no doubt employ them differently, and you'll find some who insist that such idiolectal distinctions "should" be generally observed; but the distinctions will not be perceived by hearers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All three are fine in everyday use. "Do you mind me opening the window" is technically questionable (because pedants will say that it's really asking if they would prefer somebody else to do it), but it is the sort of "mistake" that will make you sound even more like a native speaker, because it's so common.